# Unhandled exception occurs when I try to do cleanup for STL vectors

Tags: c++, winapi, vector, stl

### EDIT#1:

Replaced vectors of wchar_t pointers with vectors of wstring.

I still get buffer overflow, but now the number of crashing places in the program has drastically reduced.

### EDIT#1.1:

```
    /****************************************************/
    /*                                                  */
    /*  It was the string parser that caused buffer     */
    /*  overflow !                                      */
    /*                                                  */
    /****************************************************/
```

It must be some improper use of vectors, but that will be left for another question.

For all those who tried to help, you get +1 from me.

I have tried your answers and they all worked.

I was afraid to use wstring since I am a beginner, but thanks to the help of the community I think I have managed to learn something new.

Thank you all, again.

Thank you all again.

Regards.

### NECESSARY INFORMATION:

NOTE:

This is a simplified description, in order to keep this question as short as possible.

For further information ask additional questions, and I will provide more information.

I have a dialog box with 2 edit controls, 2 buttons and combo box.

On dialog creation, in WM_INIDIALOG, a connection is established with a database, which holds data about monthly salary of employees on a year basis.

Then primary keys of the employees are loaded into  combo box.

Tables look like this:

Table_Employee < #primary_key, ...>

Table_Salary < #pk_salary, $primary_key, January, February, ..., Year>

Relationship is one to many, since one employee has data about monthly salary for every year, like this:

|  January | ... | Year | #pk_salary| $primary_key|
|  1000.51 | ... | 2012 | 100025558 | 48089989891 |
|  2000.51 | ... | 2013 | 552025558 | 48089989891 |
...

Once a user selects a primary key from combo box , he is able to change the data about monthly salary by typing it in first edit control, and he must type in the year in the second edit control.

Entered data is held in a vectors declared like this:

```
   INT_PTR CALLBACK dlgProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, 
           WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
   {
   static vector<wchar_t*> ee; // vector for monthly salaries and a year

   // this vector holds data for all thes

      tatic vector< vector<wchar_t*> >  Pee;  years
  ...

      case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
                    // 12 months + 1 year = vector of 13 to store data 

                    ee.assign( 13, LoadedValue );                                   
                    ...
```

After user pushes the first  button , data for the month is saved in the above vector like this:

```
      case IDC_BUTTON_MONTH:
            {

                // needed, since we have vector of wchar_t*

                wchar_t *temp = new wchar_t[50]; 

                GetDlgItemInt( ... , temp, ... );

            UINT i = // ordinal of the month taken from checkbox

            ee[ i ] = temp;
```

Then user must enter year, and after pushing the second button it is stored like this:

```
      case IDC_BUTTON_YEAR:
      {

         wchar_t *temp = new wchar_t[50]; // needed, since we have vector of wchar_t*

         GetDlgItemInt( ... , temp, ... );

         ee[12] = temp;

         // This means that all the data is collected
         // so we can store this year’s data in the vector for years

         Pee.push_back(ee);
```

This way, vector Pee holds data for all the years ( 2012, 2013, ... ), and vector ee holds the specifics ( monthly salary for a certain year ).

### THE PROBLEM:

After selection in the combo box changes, I must clear all vectors, in order for new data to be stored.

When I do that I get the error, and my program snaps. Crash occurs also when I try to close the window.

If I comment out the section of the code that clears vectors, my program works, but then I can not use it to store new data, since vectors are not cleared properly.

### IMPORTANT INFORMATIONS:

Once I start program and change selection in combo box,a dialog box pops up, with 2 debuggers offered, and this message:

An unhandled exception occurred in SomeProgramName.exe[3300].

In Debug, in MS Visual Studio 2008, I have clicked on Exceptions, and checked
everything. After I start the program in Debug mode, I get the dialog box with following message:

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in MyProgramName.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while MyProgramName.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

As I have said above, after I comment out the cleanup code, error no longer occurs.

That is why I am very sure that there lies my problem.

### PROBLEMATIC CODE SNIPPETS:

Handler for WM_CLOSE:

```
   case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            // cleanup 

            for( vector<wchar_t*>::size_type i = 0; i < ee.size(); i++)
                delete[] ee[i];

            ee.clear();

            for( vector< vector<wchar_t*> >::size_type i = 0; i < pee.size(); i++)
               for( vector<wchar_t*>::size_type j = 0; j < pee[i].size(); j++)
                  delete[] pee[i][j];

            pee.clear();

            DestroyWindow( hDlg );
        }
        return TRUE;
```

Handler for combo box:

```
    case IDC_COMBO12:
        {
            if(HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE )
            {
                // cleanup 

                for( vector<wchar_t*>::size_type i = 0; i < ee.size(); i++)
                   delete[] ee[i];

                ee.clear();

                for( vector< vector<wchar_t*> >::size_type i = 0; i < pee.size(); i++)
                    for( vector<wchar_t*>::size_type j = 0; j < pee[i].size(); j++)
                       delete[] pee[i][j];

                pee.clear();

                // assign neutral values to vectors

                ee.assign( 13, L”-1” );

                for( int i = 2012; i < currentYear; i++ )
                   Pee.push_back(ee);

                // other commands, like loading data from database and so on...
```

### THE QUESTION:

Since I have a vector of pointers (`vector < wchar_t* >`) , I believe that I can’t just use `clear()` method to empty the vector since it would cause memory leaks.

That is why, in my opinion, I must delete pointer first, and only then use `clear()` method.
This is my first time using vector of `wchar_t*`, so I ask the community what am I doing wrong here?

How should I correctly reset those vectors in my handlers ?

Ask for additional information, I will gladly provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the crash: you define `vector<wchar_t*>`, fill your vector with `ee.assign( 13, L”-1” );` and with `wchar_t *temp = new wchar_t[50];` and delete with `delete[]`. All mismatched.

`delete[]` operator frees memory allocated on the heap
`ee.assign( 13, L”-1” );` passes compiler allocated objects. That is wrong. These are not on the heap and you shouldn't free that memory, but you do that when you call `delete[]`.

You may define your vector as `vector<std::wstring>` Then use it as

```
std::vector<std::wstring> v;
v.assign(10,L"xyz");
std::wstring s = L"abc";
v.push_back(s);
... etc.
v.clear(); // call destructor for every std::wstring in the vector
```

In your button handler:

```
wchar_t temp[50];
GetDlgItemTxt( ... , temp, ... );
v[i] = temp; // creates a wstring object and copies temp in there
```

You may define your vector as you did and use new and delete but **you'll need a very good reason for that**. You are taking responsibility for memory allocated for objects in the vector. You can't mix pointers allocated on the heap, on the stack or allocated statically (e.g. string literals L"-1").

```
vector<wchar_t*> v;
v.assign(10, 0); // fill in with null pointers
wchar_t *ptr = new wchar_t[10];
... fill in ptr memory with data
v.push_back(ptr);
... etc.
// Now you need to free memory you allocated manually - You do not do that
// in case of std::vector<std::wstring>
for (vector<wchar_t*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    delete[] *it;

v.clear(); // clear function calls destructor for every object in the vector.
// There is no destructor for a pointer, hence the difference between
// deallocating vector<wstring> and vector<wchar_t*>
```

Comment: This is my first time using vectors this way, can you please help me with some suggestions ?

Comment: Dmitri, the only reason I use delete[] is because I create the variable temp as described in the snippet for button clicks. I thought that since I have used keyword new there, I should do delete to release that memory. I would gladly remove delete[] if I could. That is my problem, I do not know if clear() method will empty the vectors properly, so I added delete[] to be sure.

Comment: You are correct: if you use new[] then you need to call delete[] at some point. You are also correct that if you have a vector of pointers then clear() wont release memory occupied by pointers and you need to do that yourself. Your crash happens because you try to deallocate non heap pointers ee.assign(10, L"-1"); It looks like you do not really need to store pointers in your vector, do you? Then vector<wstring> is your tool.

Comment: Use vector<wstring>; In your button handler: wchar_t temp[50]; GetDlgItemTxt( ... , temp, ... ); ee[i] = temp; // ee[i] = temp; will create a wstring object and copy temp in there

Comment: I am following your advice, and I need an answer to a short question: How do I pass wstring to the SetDlgItemText? Let's say I have vector<wstring> v, do I pass it as SetDlgItemText( ..., v , ... ), or SetDlgItemText( ..., v.c_str() , ... ) ? Thank you. Regards.

Comment: SetDlgItemText(..., v[idx].c_str(), ...) First you get wstring, hence v[index] (or using any other means provided by vector interface). Second you get the pointer to const wchar_t: wstring::c_str() function does that.

Comment: ,Thank you for a swift reply! I am making progress with wstrings, they are "cool" :)

Comment: +1 from me. Thank you for a detailed explanation, I have learned a lot. Regards.

Answer (score 5):

> Since I have a vector of pointers ( vector < wchar_t* > )

There's your problem right there. Don't use a vector of pointers. Use a vector of `std::wstring`. Then you don't have to worry about any of this.

Edit: To use `std::wstring` with `GetDlgItemText` you can do:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> ee;
wchar_t wchScratch[1024]; // should be big enough for any string you've added
GetDlgItemText(hWnd, iID, wchScratch, sizeof(wchScratch) / sizeof(wchScratch[0]));
ee.push_back(wchScratch);
```

Or, if you want something more complicated, you can do:

```
int iLength = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hWnd, iID));
std::wstring strTemp;
strTemp.resize(iLength + 1);
strTemp.resize(GetDlgItemText(hWnd, iID, &strTemp[0], strTemp.size()));
ee.push_back(strTemp);
```

Basically, nothing changes about how you get the string from the control, you are just changing how you store it.

Comment: I do not know how to use GetDlgItemText and wstring. To store edit controls text I think I need to allocate memory myself. That is why I have used wchar_t*. Can you help me with some examples of storing Dialog item's text in wstring ? Thank you.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff, in C++11, it's safe to write to everything in a `std::basic_string` before the null, treating it as if it was a C string, so you can just resize that and use `&str[0]`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: `wchar_t temp[length]; GetDlgItemText(..., ..., temp, length); std::wstring str = temp;`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Except that doesn't work too well (yet) if `length` isn't a compile-time constant.

Comment: @chris, Thank you for the reply. I do not know C++ 11, I am using UNICODE, so I ask you to clarify your comment a bit, please. Thank you. Regards.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, instead of length variable, could I use fixed number( 50 is fine for me) ?

Comment: @chris: Yes, true.  But in his example, he is using 50.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff, In C++11 (the newest version of the language), the internal characters in a `std::wstring` must be contiguous, so `&str[0]` gives you a pointer you can treat as a writable C string, except you aren't allowed to overwrite the null at the end.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: Yes, of course. In fact, it can't be a variable, it must be a constant. I was just giving a generalized example (in which `length` is assumed to be some constant).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Thank you, I will try it. Results will be reported as soon as possible. Regards.

Comment: I added examples of both chris's and Benjamin Lindley's suggestions to my answer.

Comment: @JonathanPotter,Thank you, I will try it and report my result as soon as possible. Regards.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: For the second example, you should trim the string starting at the null character. And you can use the return value of the function instead of searching for it linearly. ( *i.e. size_t sz = GetDlgItemTxt(...); strTmp.resize(sz);* )

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I am following your advice, and I need an answer to a short question: How do I pass wstring to the SetDlgItemText? Let's say I have vector<wstring> v, do I pass it as SetDlgItemText( ..., v , ... ), or SetDlgItemText( ..., v.c_str() , ... ) ? Thank you. Regards.

Comment: `std::wstring::c_str()`

Comment: @JonathanPotter, Thank you, your solution worked. The only reason I have accepted the solution bellow is because I have learned something from those comments. I still gave you +1, although I think you have deserved to get your solution accepted. Again, I have learned a lot from comments from the second solution, that is why I have accepted it, since I believe beginners can learn a lot from those comments and code snippets, I know I certainly have. Hopefully there are no hard feelings, from your part. Thanks again, so much, that code did help A LOT!. Regards.